# Javascript ES6 to ES5 conversion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es5-shim

I have this ES6 code:

```js
var occupationJson = {
  "Occupation": [{
      "value": "Engineer",
      "startDate": "2016-01-01",
      "endDate": "2016-01-31"
    },
    {
      "value": "Manager",
      "startDate": "2016-02-01",
      "endDate": "2016-02-28"
    },
    {
      "value": "Director",
      "startDate": "2016-03-05",
      "endDate": "2016-03-25"
    },
    {
      "value": "CEO",
      "startDate": "2016-04-04",
      "endDate": "2016-04-30"
    },
    {
      "value": "Board Member",
      "startDate": "2016-05-02",
      "endDate": "2099-05-31"
    }
  ]
};

var tenureJson = {
  "Tenure": [{
      "value": "Full Time",
      "startDate": "2016-01-01",
      "endDate": "2016-01-31"
    },
    {
      "value": "Part Time",
      "startDate": "2016-02-04",
      "endDate": "2016-02-28"
    },
    {
      "value": "Casual",
      "startDate": "2016-04-01",
      "endDate": "2016-04-25"
    },
    {
      "value": "Full Time",
      "startDate": "2016-05-01",
      "endDate": "2016-07-01"
    }
  ]
};

var dates = [];

// Loop through Occupation and Tenure arrays to get start and end dates
occupationJson.Occupation.forEach(function(item) {
  dates.push(item.startDate);
  dates.push(item.endDate);
});

tenureJson.Tenure.forEach(function(item) {
  dates.push(item.startDate);
  dates.push(item.endDate);
});

// Sort the dates in ascending order
dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

const occupationStartDateArray = occupationJson.Occupation.map(item => item.startDate);
const occupationEndDateArray = occupationJson.Occupation.map(item => item.endDate);

const tenureStartDateArray = tenureJson.Tenure.map(item => item.startDate);
const tenureEndDateArray = tenureJson.Tenure.map(item => item.endDate);

// Combine the start date arrays and sort them in ascending order
const allStartDateArray = [...occupationStartDateArray, ...tenureStartDateArray].sort();

// Combine the end date arrays and sort them in ascending order
const allEndDateArray = [...occupationEndDateArray, ...tenureEndDateArray].sort();

const allDatesArray = [...allStartDateArray, ...allEndDateArray];
const sortedAllDatesArray = allDatesArray.sort();
const uniqueDatesArray = [...new Set(sortedAllDatesArray)];
console.log(uniqueDatesArray);
var shortestDate = uniqueDatesArray[0];


const result = {
  "data": []
};

// Assign the shortest date to a new start date variable
let newStartDate = shortestDate;

// Loop through the unique dates and find the next shortest date
for (let i = 1; i < uniqueDatesArray.length; i++) {
  const nextShortestDate = uniqueDatesArray[i];
  let newEndDate = "";
  // Check if the next shortest date is from the all start date array
  if (allStartDateArray.includes(nextShortestDate) && nextShortestDate > newStartDate) {
    // Subtract a day from the next shortest date and assign it to the end date
    const endDate = new Date(nextShortestDate);
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
    newEndDate = endDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

    // Do something with the new start and end dates, such as logging them
    console.log(`New start date: ${newStartDate}`);
    console.log(`New end date: ${newEndDate}`);
    if (newEndDate) {
      const occupation = occupationJson.Occupation.find(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      });

      const tenure = tenureJson.Tenure.find(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      });

      const dataItem = {
        "startDate": newStartDate,
        "endDate": newEndDate,
        "Occupation": occupation ? occupation.value : "",
        "Tenure": tenure ? tenure.value : ""
      };

      if (dataItem.Occupation == "" && dataItem.Tenure == "") {

      } else {
        result.data.push(dataItem);
      }

    }


    // Assign the next shortest date to the new start date
    const startDate = new Date(newEndDate);
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    newStartDate = startDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  } else if (nextShortestDate > newStartDate) {
    // Assign the next shortest date to the end date
    newEndDate = nextShortestDate;




    // Do something with the new start and end dates, such as logging them
    console.log(`New start date: ${newStartDate}`);
    console.log(`New end date: ${newEndDate}`);
    if (newEndDate) {
      const occupation = occupationJson.Occupation.find(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      });

      const tenure = tenureJson.Tenure.find(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      });

      const dataItem = {
        "startDate": newStartDate,
        "endDate": newEndDate,
        "Occupation": occupation ? occupation.value : "",
        "Tenure": tenure ? tenure.value : ""
      };

      if (dataItem.Occupation == "" && dataItem.Tenure == "") {

      } else {
        result.data.push(dataItem);
      }
    }

    const startDate = new Date(newEndDate);
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    newStartDate = startDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }

}

console.log(result);
```

When I run this code in Browser I get the array with 10 items and which is correct.
However I need to run this in a older system which only supports ES5 scripts.
I tried to convert this into ES5 using freeze object and windows property to false but it is not working.
Issue is I am using too many const in my script and ES5 does not support const and I am not sure how to fix the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to use babel to convert the code, but it did not work.

I tried to use object freeze and Document property set to false, but that did not work either.

What can I do to port the script for running on a ES5 supported system?

Comment: So what is the version you tried to convert it too?

Comment: What did babel spit out that did not work?

Comment: Hi @epascarello  Thanks for the quick response. I am new to Babel, And somehow it's giving me the same code. There's no preset to select for ES2015. I tried force transform but the code that I get is the same as original. I apologies if this sounds dumb but I am new to this and could not find much to achieve

Comment: I am getting below error post conversion.    Set" is not defined in <eval> at line number 107

Comment: *"There's no preset to select for ES2015."*: why would you want to do that? ES6=ES2015, which is what you already have, but you want ES5. ES5 is **not** ES2015.

Comment: Hi @trincot Thanks for the answer, it worked for me like a charm. And apologies for ES2015, I was going through so many articles and messed in explaining it. What I wanted is ES5 and the code that you explained is quiet descriptive and help me understand it quiet well. Once again thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following ES5 incompatibilities in your code:

- Arrow functions: use standard `function` instead
- Template literals: use string concatenation instead
- `Set`: use a specific `Array#filter` solution instead
- `const`, and `let`: use `var` instead
- Array spread syntax: use `Array#concat` instead
- `Array#includes`: use `Array#indexOf` instead
- `Array#find`: use `Array#filter` instead

Note that you don't need to use `Object.freeze` to try to mimic `const`: That keyword is only there to protect the program from doing unintended assignments. In practice you can just replace those with `var` -- but check that the scope is still fine for the program to run correctly (this is the case in your code).

For replacing the use of `Set` (in order to remove duplicates), I used the fact that the array was already sorted, so then you just have to filter out values that have the same value following it.

Here is the code when I made the above replacements:

```js
var occupationJson = {
  "Occupation": [
    {
      "value": "Engineer",
      "startDate": "2016-01-01",
      "endDate": "2016-01-31"
    },
    {
      "value": "Manager",
      "startDate": "2016-02-01",
      "endDate": "2016-02-28"
    },
    {
      "value": "Director",
      "startDate": "2016-03-05",
      "endDate": "2016-03-25"
    },
    {
      "value": "CEO",
      "startDate": "2016-04-04",
      "endDate": "2016-04-30"
    },
    {
      "value": "Board Member",
      "startDate": "2016-05-02",
      "endDate": "2099-05-31"
    }
  ]
};

var tenureJson = {
  "Tenure": [
    {
      "value": "Full Time",
      "startDate": "2016-01-01",
      "endDate": "2016-01-31"
    },
    {
      "value": "Part Time",
      "startDate": "2016-02-04",
      "endDate": "2016-02-28"
    },
    {
      "value": "Casual",
      "startDate": "2016-04-01",
      "endDate": "2016-04-25"
    },
    {
      "value": "Full Time",
      "startDate": "2016-05-01",
      "endDate": "2016-07-01"
    }
  ]
};

var dates = [];

// Loop through Occupation and Tenure arrays to get start and end dates
occupationJson.Occupation.forEach(function(item) {
  dates.push(item.startDate);
  dates.push(item.endDate);
});

tenureJson.Tenure.forEach(function(item) {
  dates.push(item.startDate);
  dates.push(item.endDate);
});

// Sort the dates in ascending order
dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});

var occupationStartDateArray = occupationJson.Occupation.map(function (item) { return item.startDate });
var occupationEndDateArray = occupationJson.Occupation.map(function (item) { return item.endDate});

var tenureStartDateArray = tenureJson.Tenure.map(function (item) { return item.startDate});
var tenureEndDateArray = tenureJson.Tenure.map(function (item) { return item.endDate});

// Combine the start date arrays and sort them in ascending order
var allStartDateArray = occupationStartDateArray.concat(tenureStartDateArray).sort();

// Combine the end date arrays and sort them in ascending order
var allEndDateArray = occupationEndDateArray.concat(tenureEndDateArray).sort();

var allDatesArray = allStartDateArray.concat(allEndDateArray);
var sortedAllDatesArray = allDatesArray.sort();

var uniqueDatesArray = sortedAllDatesArray.filter(function (dt, i) { return dt !== sortedAllDatesArray[i+1]});
console.log(uniqueDatesArray);
var shortestDate = uniqueDatesArray[0];


var result = {
  "data": []
};

// Assign the shortest date to a new start date variable
var newStartDate = shortestDate;

// Loop through the unique dates and find the next shortest date
for (var i = 1; i < uniqueDatesArray.length; i++) {
  var nextShortestDate = uniqueDatesArray[i];
  var newEndDate="";
  // Check if the next shortest date is from the all start date array
  if (allStartDateArray.indexOf(nextShortestDate) > -1 &&  nextShortestDate>newStartDate) {
    // Subtract a day from the next shortest date and assign it to the end date
    var endDate = new Date(nextShortestDate);
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
    newEndDate = endDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

    // Do something with the new start and end dates, such as logging them
    console.log("New start date: " + newStartDate);
    console.log("New end date: " + newEndDate);
    if (newEndDate) {
      var occupation = occupationJson.Occupation.filter(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      })[0];

      var tenure = tenureJson.Tenure.filter(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      })[0];

      var dataItem = {
        "startDate": newStartDate,
        "endDate": newEndDate,
        "Occupation": occupation ? occupation.value : "",
        "Tenure": tenure ? tenure.value : ""
      };

      if (dataItem.Occupation == "" && dataItem.Tenure == "") {
      } else {
        result.data.push(dataItem);
      }
    }

   
    // Assign the next shortest date to the new start date
    var startDate=new Date(newEndDate);
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
    newStartDate =startDate.toISOString().substring(0,10);
  } else if(nextShortestDate>newStartDate){
    // Assign the next shortest date to the end date
    newEndDate = nextShortestDate;
    // Replace template strings with old-style string concatenation
    console.log("New start date: " + newStartDate);
    console.log("New end date: " + newEndDate);
    if (newEndDate) {
      var occupation = occupationJson.Occupation.filter(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      })[0];
      var tenure = tenureJson.Tenure.filter(function(item) {
        return newStartDate >= item.startDate && newEndDate <= item.endDate;
      })[0];

      var dataItem = {
        "startDate": newStartDate,
        "endDate": newEndDate,
        "Occupation": occupation ? occupation.value : "",
        "Tenure": tenure ? tenure.value : ""
      };

      if (dataItem.Occupation == "" && dataItem.Tenure == "") {
      } else {
        result.data.push(dataItem);
      }
    }
    
    var startDate = new Date(newEndDate);
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
    newStartDate = startDate.toISOString().substring(0,10);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```